# Max received message size in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed WCF service that returns the bytes of the file.

But If the file size is more than 40 MB it is giving me the error

Exception Message: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:56198/Service.svc.This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Inner Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Inner Exception Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Inner Exception Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

My Web.config is

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="01:01:00"
      openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior1" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior1">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I have made the same changes on the client side but no success